# Failed to fetch 'us.archive.ubuntu' could not connect to banjo.canonical.com:80

Tags: networking, apt, network-manager, vmware

I am running ubuntu 20.04.1 **VMware**. When its network adapter is **bridged**, I can not do `sudo apt update`, meanwhile I **can** `ping 8.8.8.8` or even `ping google.com` .
If I change its network adapter to **NAT** mode, I can do `sudo apt update`.

What are the differences? and how can I have `sudo apt update` in the bridged mode too?

Any comments would be appreciated!

here is the output of the `sudo apt update`:

```
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                             
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                      
  Could not connect to banjo.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to kazooie.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
```

My host pc has two network interfaces, both of them are connected (wired) to an access point which are connected to internet!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. How is your host PC connected to Internet: Wired or wireless, Private or public network, home or school/company? Do you have a proxy setup?

Comment: my host pc has two network interfaces, 
both of them are connected (wired) to an access point which are connected to internet!

Comment: So they are connected to the same subnet, that's probably the issue. Unplug one interface, and use only one (don't forget to use bridged connection through active one)

Comment: Any update your side Saeed?

Comment: Just change the server from US to UK or UK to US or from the server for the United States to the main server or vice versa. Then reload the software cache. Sometimes you find the servers unavailable or being down or some network issues.